# В JavaFx не могу получить размер из подключаемого стиля

Tags: java, javafx

```
HBox topElement = new HBox();
topElement.setStyle("-fx-pref-height: 100");
System.out.println(topElement.getPrefHeight()); //-1.0
```

Создаю элемент, присваиваю ему размер через подключение стиля и затем хочу использовать установленную высоту далее в коде, но получаю значение -1.0.
Причём визуально элемент получает нужный размер.
Есть ли какое-нибудь решение как получить размер установленный в стиле?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Среди стилей FX нет ни одного, который бы устанавливал размеры, хотя разговоры, что неплохо бы добавить мне встречались, может в openFX сделают.

Все что есть можно найти по ссылке,
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/javafx/javafx/1.3/docs/api/javafx.scene/doc-files/cssref.html

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, это не так.( [тык](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) - `Region` ). А по поводу вопроса - предполагаю что стиль применится после отрисовки и если вызвать `System.out.println(topElement.getPrefHeight());` позже, результат будет отличным от -1

Comment: хах, действительно у Region есть это свойство, оно и java классе есть для этого элемента. И у webview получается, согласно той же ссылке. Но это видимо все, выше по уровню ни в Parent, ни в Node этих свойств нет. Если есть задача изловчиться и сделать все размеры только стилями, тогда придется действовать от Region, а все остальные дочерние элементы фиксировать отступами/центровками и пр. Можно попробовать унаследоваться от HBox и реализовать там установку размера через стилями.

Answer (score 0):

Пока написал метод для поиска необходимого стиля в таблице стилей и извлечения значения:

```
private double getValueFromStyle(String style, String piece) throws NumberFormatException{
    int beginIndex = style.lastIndexOf(piece) + piece.length();
    int endIndex = style.indexOf(";", beginIndex);
    String strValue;
    if(endIndex == -1) {
        strValue = style.substring(beginIndex);
    } else {
        strValue = style.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);
    }
    return Double.valueOf(strValue);
}
```

Проверяем есть ли необходимый стиль в таблице, применяем метод и присваиваем полученное значение через setPrefHeight(). Далее значение можно получать через getPrefHeight().

```
if(topElement.getStyle().contains("-fx-pref-height:")) {

        try {
            double value = getValueFromStyle(topElement.getStyle(), "-fx-pref-height:");
            topElement.setPrefHeight(Double.valueOf(value));
        } catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.out.println("Ошибка преобразования строки в число");
        }

        System.out.println(topElement.getPrefHeight()); //100.0
    }
```